# How do you reuse the first parameter of a function in its second parameter?

Tags: php, function, parameters

```
function generateRandom($s,$len=count($s)){...}
```

How do you set the value of the second param of a function as the length of the first param unless otherwise it's defined?

Comment: why not generateRandom($s,$count($s)){...}

Comment: @scaisEdge What you mean?

Comment: seems you have alreday a good answer ... could that i don't understand correctly your question  ..

Answer (score 4):

It only works this way:

```
function generateRandom($s, $len=null) {
  if ($len === null) {
    $len = count($s);
  }
}
```

You cannot do any operations as the default value. It needs to be something "simple" like scalars or constants.

Comment: I was just curious if there is a way. Anyway, Thank for the answer.